# Diffrence Between 'class' and 'type' attribute in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

In jsp I have found -

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="com.test.UserDetails" />
```

By which I mean (Please correct me If I am wrong) - if a `UserDetails`  instance is already exists then it will be assigned with an id `user` and if not exist then a new `UserDetails` object is created and will be assigned with the id `user`.

But in some very rare case I have found the following `<jsp:useBean>` with `type` -

```
 <jsp:useBean id="account" type="com.test.Account" />
```

Now my questions are -

1. What the `type` do here?
2. What is difference between the `type` and `class`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the answer, `<jsp:useBean>` is discouraged/obsolete. You should instead turn towards some MVC frameworks of your interest unless it is a pure learning purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `class:` instantiates the specified bean class (i.e. creates an object
>   of the bean class) but it must have no-arg or no constructor and must
>   not be abstract.

and

> `type:` provides the bean a data type if the bean already exists in the
>   scope. It is mainly used with class or beanName attribute. If you use
>   it without class or beanName, no bean is instantiated.

Source : [Attributes and Usage of jsp:useBean action tag](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action)